# R printing numeric data without quotes

Tags: r, decimal

How could i ensure that numbers are always printed 1 digit after decimal point and without any quotes? I want a+b to print 8.0 and a1+a2 to print 4.2. **Please notice that i dont want any quotes.** I tried format() but it didnt give what i was looking for

```
> a=3
> b=5
> a+b
[1] 8
> a1=2.22
> a2=2
> a1+a2
[1] 4.22


> format(a+b,nsmall=1)
[1] "8.0"
> format(a1+a2,nsmall=1)
[1] "4.22"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `quote = FALSE` argument for `print.default` (in combination with your `format()`). You can use the `digits` argument of `format` to get a max of one digit after the decimal. Alternatively you could `round`.

```
print(format(a + b, nsmall = 1), quote = FALSE)
# [1] 8.0

## using digits

print(format(a1 + a2, nsmall = 1, digits = 1), quote = FALSE)
# [1] 4.2
print(format(1001.12321, nsmall = 1, digits = 1), quote = FALSE) 
# [1] 1001.1

## using round

print(format(round(1001.12321, 1), nsmall = 1), quote = FALSE)
# [1] 1001.1
print(format(round(a1 + a2, 1), nsmall = 1), quote = FALSE)
# [1] 4.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cat` function to avoid calling `print` on a string returned by format:

```
cat(format(a, nsmall=1), sep="\n")
```

Comment: OP has two problems, quotes, and rounding. Throw a `round(..., 1)` in there and OP will be happy.